# Java determine one dateformat from several dateformats

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format, datetime-format

We want to get a correct dateformat from LOG files generated by different systems with different language and log mechanism.

We thought this can be done be a `SimpleDataFormat.parse` and `try-catch exception` way. But the follow code shows a problem.

```java
    String tryparseString = "18-01-22 00:03:34:071";
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(sdf1.parse(tryparseString));
        System.out.println(sdf1.format(sdf1.parse(tryparseString)));
        System.out.println("Yeah! We found a CAN PARSE datefromat = " + sdf1.toPattern());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        System.out.println(sdf2.parse(tryparseString));
        System.out.println(sdf2.format(sdf2.parse(tryparseString)));
        System.out.println("Yeah! We found a CAN PARSE datefromat = " + sdf2.toPattern());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This got a result as:

```
Sat Jan 22 00:03:34 CST 18
0018-01-22 00:03:34
Yeah! We found a CAN PARSE datefromat = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
Mon Jan 22 00:03:34 CST 2018
18-01-22 00:03:34:000
Yeah! We found a CAN PARSE datefromat = yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS
```

So, `"18-01-22 00:03:34:071"` can both be formatted with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and `yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS`.

The former one is far away correct.

So, is there a way to determine a correct dateformat from serveral dateformats?

Comment: Well, do you or do you not want to retain the millisecond precision information?  Just because both patterns work does not tell us which one you want to use.  And by the way, consider using the Java 8 date/time API which makes things a lot easier.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think it's quite easy to find the former one is incorrect `yyyy` should only be `0018` compatible not `18` compatible? But SimpleDateFormat not think so?

Comment: @rufushuang you can prioritize formats before parsing. This time does not contain the Time zone Info And that is not a good practice

Comment: Two messages: (1) Never use `SimpleDateFormat`, it’s long outdated and notoriously troublesome. [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with. (2) I believe that `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` with default settings will solve your problem just like that.

Comment: @OleV.V. I it should be sdf2, but the result and problem is still the same. The DateTimeFormatter works great on the case provided above, i will give it some more shot to test if it can survive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.time` to the rescue.

```
    String[] formats = {
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS"
    };

    String tryparseString = "18-01-22 00:03:34:071";

    for (String format : formats) {
        try {
            LocalDateTime.parse(tryparseString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
            System.out.println("Yeah! We found a CAN PARSE date format = " + format);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            System.out.println(dtpe);
        }
    }
```

This prints:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '18-01-22 00:03:34:071' could not be parsed at index 0
Yeah! We found a CAN PARSE datefromat = yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS
```

In other words, the first format, `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, fails to parse your sample string, and the second succeeds as you wanted it to.

If you still experience a case where a `DateTimeFormatter` parses a string it shouldn’t, you may try `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)`. It may catch a few more non-matching strings. In this case you will need `uuuu` and `uu` instead of `yyyy` and `yy` in the format patterns, though.

Comment: Pass all test case on jdk6 and joda-time. Considering my project support of jdk6, so using `joda-time` instead of `java.time.format`. The `joda-time` doesn't have the `STRICT` style config?

Comment: (1) Joda-Time is a largely finished project; on Java 6 I would clearly prefer [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) over Joda. (2) I don’t know Joda-Time, sorry, so cannot tell. If it doesn’t distinguish between lenient and strict, it may be because it is always strict?

Answer (score 0):

Check with below code snippet. You can have a list of your data format with a priority. After it finds one suitable it will break unless continuing.

for

```
 String tryparseString = "18-01-22 00:03:34:071";



     public void parseDate(String tryparseString) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");

        ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat> simpleDateFormats = new ArrayList<>();
        simpleDateFormats.add(sdf1);//add as your priority
        simpleDateFormats.add(sdf2);

        for (int a = 0; a < simpleDateFormats.size(); a++) {

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = simpleDateFormats.get(a);

            try {

                System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse(tryparseString));
                System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(simpleDateFormat.parse(tryparseString)));
                System.out.println("Yeah! We found a CAN PARSE datefromat = " + sdf1.toPattern());
                break;//When Meets it will breack the parsing
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it's still quite a difficulty to choose a priority when dateformats has a large variety.

Comment: As per my knowledge when logging it contains the time zone information. You can prioritize it by the pattern with more data of the time. If data are same then no problem of the priority of them.